# Perl File Name Change

Tags: perl, unix

I am studying and extending a Perl script written by others. It has a line:

```
@pub=`ls $sourceDir | grep '\.htm' | grep -v Default |  head  -550`;
foreach (@pub) {

   my $docName = $_;
   chomp($docName);
   $docName =~ s/\.htm$//g;
    ............}
```

I know that it uses a UNIX command firstly to take out all the htm files, then get rid of file extension.

Now I need to do one thing, which is also very important. That is, I need to change the file name of the actual files stored, by replacing the white space with underscore. I am stuck here because I am not sure whether I should follow his code style, achieving this by using UNIX, or I should do this in Perl? The point is that I need to modify the real file on the disk, not the string which used to hold the file name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be faster to use [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.6/lib/File/Copy.pm) to move the file to its new name rather than using this method which forks off a new process, spawns a new shell, etc.  it takes more memory and is slower than doing it within perl itself.

edit.. you can get rid of all that backtick b.s., too, like this

```
my @files = grep {!/Default/} glob "$sourcedir/*.html";
```

Comment: Since the source and destination is in the same directory, you can use `rename`. See `perldoc -f rename` for details.

Comment: I used move(), but always fail, do you think this is a permission issue?

Comment: It very well could be a permissions issue if the euid/egid of the script doesn't match the ownership of the files.  what error is it giving when it fails? try adding 'or die "$!\n"' to the line where you're using the move.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should help (not tested)

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
use File::Copy;
use strict;

my @files = grep { ! /Default/ } glob("$sourceDir/*.htm");
# I didn't implement the "head  -550" part as I don't understand the point.
# But you can easily do it using `splice()` function.

foreach my $file (@files) {
    next unless (-f $file);   # Don't rename directories!
    my $dirname = dirname($file); # file's directory, so we rename only the file itself.
    my $file_name = basename($file); # File name fore renaming.
    my $new_file_name = $file_name;
    $new_file_name =~ s/ /_/g; # replace all spaces with underscores
    rename($file, File::Spec->catfile($dirname, $new_file_name))
        or die $!; # Error handling - what if we couldn't rename?
}
```

Comment: better use y/\s/_/s instead of s/ /_/g? Paul

Comment: I did put the code as you did. But I got the error:" Global symbol "@pub" requires explicit package name", can you plz help?

Comment: so you didn't use the code as DVK provided... without seing your current code I'm guessing my @pub... should do the trick...

Comment: @pavel: regex backslash patterns don't work in y/// or tr///. Only those sequences that map to a single particular character work, e.g. \t or \n.